# Set Min Height with Jquery to avoid mobile issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, viewport

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm looking to change this working function so that instead of setting my ".nav_menu" div's height to half of the viewport, it sets the min-height.

```
var menu = jQuery(".nav_menu");
  jQuery(window).resize("resizeMenu");
  function resizeMenu() {
    menu.height(jQuery(window).height() / 2);
  }
resizeMenu();
```

Now the reason I don't want to do something like this...

```
$('.nav_menu').css("min-height", "50vh");
```

Or just do that directly in css, is because of the height recalculating issue that presents itself on mobile when the address bar hides. The function above bypasses that issue, but is set to work with height, not min-height.

Ultimately my goal is to be able to use the VH or % unit value for the min height of an element, without creating the issue on android that when you scroll from the top, and the browser address bar hides, it recalculates the viewport size, thus changing the output value of a % or VH unit. So any solution for that is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Would doing a check within the function solve the issue? That why you're not setting the element's height unless it is needed, which is basically what the `min-height` style does. Something like:

```
var menu = jQuery(".nav_menu");
jQuery(window).resize("resizeMenu");
function resizeMenu() {
    var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    if (menu.height < windowHeight / 2){
        menu.height( windowHeight / 2);
    }
}
resizeMenu();
```

Comment: Hrmm I did try this but it didn't work, thanks though!